# Testing nodejs with mocha and supertest. How to get the app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I am trying to test a nodejs app with supertest, and I cannot get a single route to run.  I've narrowed the problem down.  In my test file, I start with this:

```
var app = express();  // this is the problem, this isn't really the app, right?

// testing this dummy works fine, but I want the real one
app.get('/user', function(req, res){
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'tobi' });
});

describe('GET /user', function(){
  it('respond with json', function(done){
    request(app)
      .get('/user')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200, done);
  })
})
```

...and this test passes.  But of course, that dummy /user route is not the one I want to test.  I want to test routes defined in my "real" app, defined at ./server.js.

Even if I simply move the dummy `app.get('/user', function...` definition to my "real" server.js file, the one that I launch with nodemon, this simple test fails with a 404.

So what does this line really do: `var app = express();`, and how do I get hold of the `app` configured in my server.js file so I can test it?

Comment: You don't normally mix your test into your app. You create your app server and run it. Then you have run your mocha tests from the command line, against localhost.

Comment: @CargoMeister - could you explain how I do that?  Like, in this test get() do I give it the full url of route on localhost?  Where do I put the test file?

Comment: The only thing that goes into the test.js file is what is in the describe. Doesn't know anything about your server file, except the api. And then yes, use the full URL: http://.localhost:8081/user, assuming that you are using the default port. So basically, just split the two files on the blank space in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `export` your app from `server.js`. Once you do this, you can `require` the app in your test files.

### server.js

```
var express = require('express')

var app = express();

// Your routes here...

// At end of file
module.exports = app;
```

### test.js *(in a `test` directory)*

```
var api = require('../server.js'),
    request = require('supertest')(api);

describe('noshers', function() {

    it('doesn\'t allow GET requests', function(done) {
        request
            .get('/foo')
            .expect(405, done);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but requiring my server.js causes an error like `Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE:::<port>`.  That server.js file tells the app to listen, and I think this error is about listening twice.

Comment: You don't need to start the server first if you use this method. To quote the SuperTest documentation: *"if the server is not already listening for connections then it is bound to an ephemeral port for you so there is no need to keep track of ports."*

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I'm confused about organization.  My server file *does* start listening, because it needs to listen for the app to run.  If I change the app file to be in "test mode", like skipping the listen, then I'll be testing a different code path than the real app.  My work around right now is to make the test have no relation to the app's server, and use `var server = supertest.agent("http://localhost:3000");` this to make my server calls against.

Comment: **Firstly:** What you are doing is fine, but that doesn't answer the question you originally asked, so it's helpful to actually solve it properly for future readers of this post. **Secondly:** You don't need to change your server code at all to export the app and test it with SuperTest. **1:** Make sure your app *isn't* already running and listening on port 3000. **2:** Require your exported app in your test file. **3:** Run your test. SuperTest will bind the app to an ephemeral port and run the tests - It doesn't matter that your server file calls `app.listen`